# GAE - Error: "The method POST is not allowed for this resource"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm trying to understand how to edit or update a model. I have tried several scenarios which sometimes give an error message: 405 Method Not Allowed - The method POST is not allowed for this resource. Below is my code:

The Python Models:

```
import os 
import webapp2
import wsgiref.handlers
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class MessageModel(db.Model):
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Message(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        doRender(self,'message.htm')

    def post(self):
        m = MessageModel()
        m.content = self.request.get('content')
        m.put()

        self.redirect('/view') 

class View(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        que = db.Query(MessageModel)
        messageview_list = que.fetch(999)

        doRender(self,
                 'view.htm', 
                 {'messageview_list': messageview_list })


class Edit(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):

        doRender(self,'edit.htm')    

    def post(self):

        updated_content = self.request.get('content')

        content_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                   "FROM MessageModel "
                                   "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1")

        messageview_list = content_query.fetch(1)
        m = MessageModel()
        m.content = self.request.get(updated_content)
        m.put()

        doRender(self,
                 'edit.htm', 
                 {'messageview_list': messageview_list })


class Main(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        doRender(self,'index.htm')


def doRender(handler, tname = 'index.htm', values = { }):
    temp = os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'templates/' + tname)
    if not os.path.isfile(temp):
    return False

    newval = dict(values)
    newval['path'] = handler.request.path

    outstr = template.render(temp, newval)
    handler.response.out.write(outstr)
    return True




app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Main),
                   ('/message', Message),
                   ('/view', View),                                                                          
                   ('/edit', Edit)], 
                   debug=True)
```

The HTML Form:

```
{% for messageview in messageview_list %}

<form method="post" action="/edit">
    <p>
        <textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="60" MAXLENGTH=60>
        {{ messageview.content }}</textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update"/> 
      </p>
</form>
      {% ifnotequal error None %}
       <p>
       {{ error }}
       </p>
      {% endifnotequal %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I do not understand your code. How do you start your application? How does the url look like, which results in a GET? Have you looked in your resulting HTML after the GET?

Comment: what's the question? If you have a handler defined for POST requests then your app can deal with them. If you don't then you'll get the error you note. But what is the actual problem? Perhaps post your handler mapping code?

Comment: I edit my post - and replace it with whole edit.py hope that someone can explain me how the function to edit ore update a POST works

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the indentation is due to copy/paste, but make sure that the `post()` and `get()` functions are actually indented inside of your class.

In your form, you have `<textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="60" MAXLENGTH=60>`, but in your `def post()` you use `updated_content = self.request.get('content')`, which is looking for the `content` keyword in the request. Also, your edit doesn't look like it is doing what you want it to do. In order to edit an entity, the basic outline of the process is 1.) Retrieve the entity (so do as you do, query using some parameter); 2.) Modify the properties of the entity however you want; and 3.) `put()` the entity back in the datastore.

From your code, it looks like you are retrieving the last entity entered into the datastore, but then creating a new model instead of editing that one (assuming that is what you want to do - not quite sure if that is accurate :) ). If you are looking to modify the entity that is returned, this should work:

```
def post(self):

    updated_content = self.request.get('message')
    content_query = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                               "FROM MessageModel "
                               "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1")

    # Your query will always return just one entity (due to the LIMIT),
    # but you can use get() here instead of fetch(1)
    latest_model = content_query.get()

    # Update the model's content property
    latest_model.content = updated_content
    latest_model.put()

    # Assuming you want to output that model, you'd output it now
    doRender(self,
             'edit.htm', 
             {'messageview_list': latest_model })
```

Comment: RocketDonkey. Thank you very much! Your explanation helps me! I wil study it and when it's working i wil rate it as the correct answer.

Comment: @HendrikusGodvliet No problem, but if you are still running into errors let's get them sorted out! Are you still getting the POST error? Looks like there are a few things that we could tidy up a bit, so happy to help out however I can :)

Comment: RocketDonkey Yes i still getting the POST eror - how can i show you my new code - i can' t go on with edit the old code in this post?

Comment: @HendrikusGodvliet You should be able to edit the post and put your code in. You have `def post()` correctly defined, so perhaps you can include the full traceback you receive? Maybe the error is being thrown by a different call.

Comment: @HendrikusGodvliet I put together a small version of your app and all seems to be working. The main reason you get the errors you're specifying are when the methods aren't properly defined in each class. If you are getting this when you hit `/edit`, make sure that `def post(self):` is properly indented under the `Edit` class (the same goes for `def get(self)`. I suspect the issue is in the indentation somewhere, so we'll get there!

Comment: @HendrikusGodvliet Sorry, missed the edit you tried to add (I would actually suggest adding it to your own post :) ). I would definitely check your indentation first though - remember that if `def get()` is on the same indentation level as the class, it will not be considered part of the class (and the class will therefore not have a `get()` method, which would result in the response you are seeing).

Comment: @HendrikusGodvliet Okay, I am going to send you a series of links to some Github Gist's - I have that exact code running right now and it works fine (there are a few design choices that could be optimized, but I think that is outside the scope for now :) ).

Comment: @HendrikusGodvliet main.py: https://gist.github.com/3980660, edit.htm: https://gist.github.com/3980684. You can test it by running it on your dev server and going to http://localhost:xxxx/edit, modifying the result and then submitting (right now it takes you back to view.htm, so make sure you have that defined as well). Let me know if that works (if not, I'm slowly running out of ideas :) ).